# How do I remove devEdpress notification appears every time when I reload the page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress Image slider with trial version, when I reload the page it notifies me to buy license, where do I find the code behind this notification and remove it?
I found in inspect elements.

```
<table><tbody><tr><td style="width:100%;padding:2px 10px">You have installed DevExpress Products in Evaluation Mode – To purchase a license, please visit us online at: <a style="color:#303030" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.devexpress.com/purchase">www.devexpress.com/purchase</a>.<br>If you’ve purchased DevExpress Products and need to register your license, please review: <a style="color:#303030" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/K18106.aspx">www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/K18106.aspx</a>.</td><td><img src="/DXR.axd?r=1_20-1cuda" alt="Close" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display=&quot;none&quot;;"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Generally you remove these through buying the component. These screens are used by component vendors to ensure you don't push out trial copies into production in an attempt to use their components without paying for it. You can't remove this sort of things without buying the license as the code that generates this will be within the component dll itself.

Comment: hmm, yeah I guess so I can remove them. I thought there might be a way to get rid of em without buying the products.
Lets take license ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message appears only if you are using the trial version of DevExpress products. You can click the close button on the right to temporarily remove the message from the screen and see how a web page looks. Usually this is sufficient for evaluation purposes. If you decide that DevExpress controls meet your requirements and you wish to continue using them, you would need to purchase a license after the trial period ends, [register installed products](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18106) and the message will automatically disappear after that.